# Javascript/Html : EventListener not firing when html doc is embedded in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am currently trying to get a signature pad to work within the context of my application. I am using a sample page from the user guide to test. I can visit my sample page at localhost:20617/tests/sigPadTest.html and everything works fine. However, in another place in my app, I am dynamically loading html forms into an iframe. When I do this, no breakpoint in the function `SignResponse(event)` is ever hit and my program fails. How can I overcome this? why does embedding an html document in an iframe cause this to happen? You can find my test document, sigPadTest.html and an example of how I am embedding it in an iframe below. For reference, when I embed in iframe, the method StartSign() does get called and breakpoints are hit, it does not error at all, but nothing happens after that. i.e.: no response is received and SignResponse is not triggered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
  <title>ePadLink SigCaptureWeb SDK Sample</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var imgWidth;
    var imgHeight;
    function StartSign()
     {
        var canvasObj = document.getElementById('cnv');
        canvasObj.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvasObj.width, canvasObj.height);
        document.FORM1.sigRawData.value = "Signature Raw Data: ";
        document.FORM1.sigImageData.value = "Signature Image Data: ";
        imgWidth = canvasObj.width;
        imgHeight = canvasObj.height;
        var message = { "firstName": "", "lastName": "", "eMail": "", "location": "", "imageFormat": 1, "imageX": imgWidth, "imageY": imgHeight, "imageTransparency": false, "imageScaling": false, "maxUpScalePercent": 0.0, "rawDataFormat": "ENC", "minSigPoints": 25, "penThickness": 3, "penColor": "#000000" };

        document.addEventListener('SigCaptureWeb_SignResponse', SignResponse, false);
        var messageData = JSON.stringify(message);
        var element = document.createElement("SigCaptureWeb_ExtnDataElem");
        element.setAttribute("SigCaptureWeb_MsgAttribute", messageData);
        document.documentElement.appendChild(element);
        var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
        evt.initEvent("SigCaptureWeb_SignStartEvent", true, false);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
    function SignResponse(event)
    {
        var str = event.target.getAttribute("SigCaptureWeb_msgAttri");
        var obj = JSON.parse(str);
        SetValues(obj, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    }
    function SetValues(objResponse, imageWidth, imageHeight)
    {
        var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objResponse));
        var ctx = document.getElementById('cnv').getContext('2d');

            if (obj.errorMsg != null && obj.errorMsg!="" && obj.errorMsg!="undefined")
            {
                alert(obj.errorMsg);
            }
            else
            {
                if (obj.isSigned)
                {
                    document.FORM1.sigRawData.value += obj.rawData;
                    document.FORM1.sigImageData.value += obj.imageData;
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function ()
                    {
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
                    }
                    img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + obj.imageData;
                }
            }
    }

    function ClearFormData()
    {
         document.FORM1.sigRawData.value = "Signature Raw Data: ";
         document.FORM1.sigImageData.value = "Signature Image Data: ";

    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="ClearFormData()">
  <h2>ePadLink SigCaptureWeb SDK Sample Page</h2>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="0" width="500">
    <tr>
      <td height="100" width="500">
        <canvas id="cnv" name="cnv" width="500" height="100"></canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <canvas name="SigImg" id="SigImg" width="500" height="100"></canvas>
  <form action="$$URL$$" name=FORM1>
    <p>
      <input id="SignBtn" name="SignBtn" type="button" value="Sign" onclick="StartSign()" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="bioSigData">
      <INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="sigImgData">
      <BR>
      <BR>
      <TEXTAREA NAME="sigRawData" ROWS="20" COLS="50">Signature Raw Data: </TEXTAREA>
      <TEXTAREA NAME="sigImageData" ROWS="20" COLS="50">Signature Image Data: </TEXTAREA>
    </p>
  </form>
  <br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

and embedding my html document inside another html document like this:

```
<iframe data-bind="attr:{src:href,title:title}" style="width: 100%; min-height: 800px" src="EformViewer.aspx?EformID=5&amp;DocID=29" title="11111111Created: 2016-09-27T11:52:22.677 by admin <br />Modified: 2016-09-27T11:52:00 by admin<br />Row: 2/<i>2</i>, DocID: 29<br />Separator: , Divider: "></iframe>
```

Comment: Where is the code that triggers the `SigCaptureWeb_SignResponse` event?

Comment: this event is triggered by the hardware device signature pad

Comment: So it sounds like that event isn't firing when the page is inside an iframe. Is there an overlay on the iframe? Does signing work? Maybe the event fires on the parent document?... I think you may end up needing to contact the company that created the software for that device.

Comment: @peggy were you able to get a solution ?

Comment: @RosemolJ Yes, it was an issue with the hardware unfortunately so I had it replaced